# append onclick to links javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

To append:

```
_target="_blank"
```

To all links in an HTML page I use:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].target="_blank";
  }
```

But for some reason, when I use the exact same code and try to append:

```
onclick="alert(2)"
```

Like so:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].onclick="alert(2)";
  }
```

It does not work.

Can anyone show me how to do this? (preferably in javascript instead of jQuery)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your original query with a slight modification:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function() { alert(2) };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
links[i].onclick = function() { alert(2); };
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers show, the `onclick` property should contain a function. If you really want to assign a Javascript code string, you can do it with `setAttribute`.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].setAttribute('onclick', "alert(2)");
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
```